# set Multiple session for login in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am trying to allow multi user login in my application like gmail.

I have changed in UserIdentity component.

But I want to do like myurl should like this

http://www.testdomain.com/user/1/controller/action // for first login user

if same user login with next account then

http://www.testdomain.com/user/2/controller/action // this should open the second user session with UI

How can I do this in Yii framework.

is this possible to do? and if yes then how to do that.

make sute at one time I need to allow two sessions login but if It is 1 in URL then it should show the first user data and it is 2 then second user data.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely feasible.

You need store "user_type" into session and cookie when login.

For example, store user_type as one if the user login from url1,
store "user_type" as two if user login from another url.

And then

```
if ($_SESSION["user_type"]==1){
        // show user's page1
} else {
        // show user's page2
}
```

Why need a cookie?

Beacuse you should use it to autologin.